# Returning different types of data depending on parameter in Swift

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I have different clases, each one has their methods that return different types. I don't want to repeat myself writing the same thing over and over again - feels like a bad practice, and I want to know if is possible with one  function return the objects depending on the parameter given in the function. As an example:

```
func myFunction(type: String) -> ?? {
   switch type {
       case myClass1:
           return objectTypeMyClass1
           break;
       case myClass2:
           return objectTypeMyClass2
           break;
       case myClass3:
           return objectTypeMyClass3
           break;
       default: 
           break;
   }
}
```

Is that a good practice? It is possible.

Comment: You can try use AnyObject, but if is good practice? It depends... Apple usually this approach, for example in target action selectors.

Comment: You should take a look at using a generic type, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enum` as a container for a type (something similar to how Apple have done optionals):

```
enum TypeContainer {
    case SomeInt(Int)
    case SomeString(String)
    case SomeBool(Bool)

    init(int: Int) {
        self = .SomeInt(int)
    }

    init(string: String) {
        self = .SomeString(string)
    }

    init(bool: Bool) {
        self = .SomeBool(bool)
    }
}

let a = TypeContainer(string: "123")
let b = TypeContainer(int: 88)
let c = TypeContainer(bool: true)

switch a {
case .SomeInt(let i):
    println(i)
case .SomeString(let s):
    println(s)
case .SomeBool(let b):
    println(b)
default:
    break
}
```